# Nested If is not working

Tags: google-apps-script

when i ran the program without the *""*** if, it works but when i added it in it didnt. could someone tell me what im doing wrong here. Thank you!

```
 function onEdit(event) {
 // assumes source data in sheet named Clients
 // target sheet of move to named Closed List
 // test column with "Y" is col 14 or N
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var s = event.source.getActiveSheet();
 var r = event.source.getActiveRange();

if(s.getName() == "Clients" && r.getColumn() == 14 && r.getValue() == "Y") {
 **if(s.getName() == "Clients" && r.getColumn() == 15 && r.getValue() == "Jan") {**
var row = r.getRow();
var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Closed List");
    var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);
    s.deleteRow(row);
    **}**
  }

}
```

Comment: @Abhishek Sorry, what do you mean? because my column 14 is Y and my 15 is Jan but it doesn't register for some reason.

Comment: Take a look if s.getName() == "Clients" && r.getColumn() == 14 && r.getValue() == "Y" these three conditions are true then definitely below lines s.getName() == "Clients" && r.getColumn() == 15 && r.getValue() == "Jan" return false( r.getColumn() == 15 and r.getValue() == "Jan" returns false).

Comment: if you want to add more months then better use switch for r.getColumn().

Comment: @Abhishek Sorry, i think i misinterpretted it the 1st time. i wanted it to be meeting all the criteria which means column 14 and column 15's criteria has to be met.

Comment: but how about r.getColumn()? It always give you one value 14 or 15.

Comment: i wanted it to be if column 14 is Y then check if column 15 is Jan

Comment: I updated my answer. Take look on it.

Comment: that means that if its Y or Jan it will run right? is there a way where i can have Y & Jan?

Comment: Y and Jan for single column for 14 as well as 15?

Comment: isnt column 14 = column N? and 15 = Column O?

Comment: Check with updated one and use loop then for values with possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

Try if else ladder than nested if like this

```
var row; var numColumns; var targetSheet;
if(s.getName() == "Clients" && r.getColumn() == 14 && r.getValue() == "Y") {
row = r.getRow();
numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Closed List");
var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);
s.deleteRow(row);
} else if(s.getName() == "Clients" && r.getColumn() == 15 && r.getValue() == "Jan") {
row = r.getRow();
numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Closed List");
var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);
s.deleteRow(row);
}
```

//Updated Logic as per comment

```
var row; var numColumns; var targetSheet;
if(s.getName() == "Clients" && ((r.getColumn() == 14 && r.getValue() == "Y") || (r.getColumn() == 15 && r.getValue() == "Jan"))) {
row = r.getRow();
numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Closed List");
var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);
s.deleteRow(row);
}
```

Comment: Nested if not worked because look r.getColumn() gives you 14 which is true and again in inner if statement you are checking r.getColumn() equals to 15 which is not possible so it returns false.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a problem of nesting. You misunderstood what `r.getColumn()` does: it "*[Returns the starting column position for this range](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getColumn())*" `r`. This means that getColumn() will return the same value if you call it twice in a row without changing the active (selected) range.

Looking at your comments, it seems you want to test the value in both columns 14 and 15.

So try and replace `r.getColumn() == 14 && r.getValue() == "Y"` with:

`r.offset(0, 13, 1, 1).getValue() == "Y"`

or even with:

`r.getValues()[0][13] == "Y"`

Same logic with `r.getColumn() == 15 && r.getValue() == "Jan"`.

N.B.: I assume that you're testing values on the first row; if you want to address row `i` instead, then replace the `0` by `i-1`.

Comment: with i, do you mean do a loop to check for all rows??

Comment: what does the 1,1 at the back of (0,13,1,1)